# customized scrollview

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I want to have a scrollview that looks something like shown in the image. I have a rooted device at my disposal . I think its possible to change by making some changes in the source of android itself .

Please guide me on this.
[image: scrollview for the list]

Thanks in advance

Comment: i try this but did not get success. i create with custom color. and image. but if you want to make like this then you have to write code up key & down key of scroll view. and i think this is not possible as per my opinion  because i put two image button on top and bottom. in between i use custom scroll bar. now if i use scroll in different layout then how can i put other view in that scroll ? so. i try lot but sorry.if you will get success then share with me.

Comment: thanks for the comment . trying that now . will let you know if i succeed